# Relationship between cyclotomic polynomial modulo a prime and its associated quotient group?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\Phi_m(x)$ where $\Phi_m(x)$ is a $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial .

And it can be factorized over modulo $p$  as follows

$\Phi_m(x)\equiv F_1(X)F_2(X)\ldots F_k(X) \mod p$

Is there any relationship between  $F_i(X)$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$) and $\mathbb{Z}_m^*/\langle p \rangle$ ??

Comment: Just checking: By “$\Bbb Z_m^*/\langle p\rangle$“ you mean the units of the finite ring modulo the multiplicative subgroup generated by $p$?

Comment: yeah that's right

Comment: Assuming that $\gcd(m,p)=1$ the following can be said. Let's fix a primitive root $\zeta$. Then the exponents $j$ of zeros $\zeta^j$ of a factor $F_i(x)$ form a coset of $\langle p\rangle$ inside $\Bbb{Z}_m^*$. Such cosets are often called *cyclotomic cosets* for this very reason.

Comment: Related questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/305111),[2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/232216), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1905031/11619). More links to related questions collected at those. The question is at the core of much finite field Galois theory because over a finite field **ALL** irreducible polynomials are factors of some cyclotomic polynomial :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying me. Cyclotomic polynomial is a very beautiful entity :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So those cosets are factors themselves???

Comment: Not quite. You get an irreducible factor $F(X)=\prod(x-\zeta^j)$ with $j$ ranging over a coset.

Comment: I got it!!! But how about the case when $\Phi_m(X)$ cannot be factored into linear terms? In that case, order of each coset is more than 1.

Comment: Correct. This happens if and only if $m$ is a factor of $p-1$ (still assuming $\gcd(m,p)=1$).